# Qual é a diferença entre os hooks useMemo e useCallback do React?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Sei que `useMemo` e `useCallback` são dois novos *hooks* do React. No entanto, ainda não entendi muito bem a diferença entre elas.

Qual a diferença entre "*retornar um valor memoizado*" e "*retornar um callback memoizado*"? O *callback* não seria um tipo de valor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A única coisa que ambos os hooks possuem em comum é de que retornam *algo* memoizado. Apesar disso ser o suficiente para confundir a funcionalidade de ambos, ao longo da resposta ficará bem claro quais são as diferenças.

## `useCallback`

```
const callbackMemoizado = useCallback(
  () => {
    // callback
  },
  [/* array de dependências */],
);
```

O [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) retorna um *callback* memoizado. O que isso significa?

A cada renderização do seu componente, todo o código que está nele é executado novamente. Portanto, as funções são re-declaradas, e uma nova referência (na memória) é alocada para cada função. O `useCallback` faz com que sua função seja redefinida apenas quando necessário, assim mantendo a mesma referência.

O **array de dependências** é o responsável por definir se o callback será redefinido ou não. Caso haja uma mudança em alguma das dependências, será redefinido. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function App() {
  const [contador, setContador] = React.useState(0);

  const callbackAtualizado = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('callbackAtualizado:', contador);
  }, [contador]);
  
  const callbackNaoAtualizado = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('callbackNaoAtualizado:', contador);
  }, []);

  function incrementar() {
    setContador(contador + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>contador: {contador}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementar}>Incrementar</button>
      <button onClick={callbackAtualizado}>callbackAtualizado</button>
      <button onClick={callbackNaoAtualizado}>callbackNaoAtualizado</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Neste exemplo, para que o `callbackAtualizado` consiga exibir o novo valor do estado `contador`, foi preciso criar uma nova referência sempre que esse estado foi atualizado, já que está no array de dependências.

Enquanto isso, a referência do `callbackNaoAtualizado` nunca foi modificada, por isso ele sempre exibe o estado do primeiro render, que é `0`.

### Observação sobre o array de dependências

O exemplo acima foi feito com o objetivo de demonstração. Você deve evitar utilizar variáveis (ou funções) externas ao `useCallback` sem colocá-las no array de dependências. Se está fazendo isso, provavelmente sua aplicação está com algum problema de lógica.

Existe um [plugin do ESLint](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) chamado [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) que possui uma regra para validar o array de dependências. Essa regra apontaria um problema no `callbackNaoAtualizado`:

> React Hook `useCallback` has a missing dependency: 'contador'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

Em outras palavras, "*O React Hook `useCallback` tem uma dependência faltando: 'contador'. Inclua-a ou remova o array de dependências.*".

Caso utilizássemos uma função externa chamada `funcao` sem adicionar no array de dependências, a mensagem seria:

> React Hook `useCallback` has a missing dependency: 'funcao'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'funcao' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in `useCallback`.

"*O React Hook `useCallback` tem uma dependência faltando: 'funcao'. Inclua-a ou remova o array de dependências. Se 'funcao' muda com muita frequência, encontre o componente pai que o define e envolva essa definição em um `useCallback`.*"

## `useMemo`

```
const valorMemoizado = useMemo(
  () => {
    return; /* retorne algo a ser armazenado em `valorMemoizado` */
  },
  [/* array de dependências */],
);
```

O [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) retorna um *valor* memoizado. Como isso se difere do `useCallback`?

1. O `useMemo` é executado durante a renderização. Ele não é uma função a ser chamada, mas sim o retorno da função passada para o `useMemo`.
2. Enquanto o `useCallback` é utilizado para manter a referência da função passada, o `useMemo` deve ser utilizado para **cálculos caros**, e não para guardar a referência de um objeto, por exemplo.

O `useMemo` recalculará o valor memoizado apenas quando uma das dependências forem modificadas, segue o mesmo raciocínio explicado para o `useCallback`.

Utilize o `useMemo` para a otimização de desempenho da sua aplicação, não como uma garantia semântica. No futuro, o React pode escolher "esquecer" algum valor memoizado e recalculá-lo na próxima renderização para, por exemplo, liberar memória de componentes que não estão em tela no momento.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```js
function expensiveCalc(max) {
  const start = Date.now();
  let counter = 0;
  while (Date.now()-start < max) counter++;
  return counter;
}

function App() {
  const [contador, setContador] = React.useState(2000);
  const [horario, setHorario] = React.useState(new Date());
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // useEffect apenas para forçar uma re-renderização a cada segundo
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setHorario(oldHorario =>
        new Date(oldHorario.getTime() + 1000)
      );
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

  const calculoMemoizado = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log(`Calculo realizado para`, contador);
    return expensiveCalc(contador);
  }, [contador]);

  const calculoNaoAtualizado = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log(`Calculo nao atualizado realizado para`, contador);
    return expensiveCalc(contador);
  }, []);

  function incrementar() {
    setContador(contador + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{horario.toLocaleString('pt-BR')}</p>
      <p>contador: {contador}</p>
      <p>calculoMemoizado: {calculoMemoizado}</p>
      <p>calculoNaoAtualizado: {calculoNaoAtualizado}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementar}>Incrementar</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Adicionei o horário atual com `useEffect` no exemplo acima apenas para ficar mais visível o congelamento da interface enquanto o "cálculo caro" está sendo realizado, e também para mostrar que o `useMemo` não é recalculado a qualquer atualização de estado.

A função `expensiveCalc` não realiza nada demais, apenas um cálculo caro para exemplificação. Obtive ela [nesse artigo](https://medium.com/swlh/memoization-speed-up-your-code-by-storing-expensive-calculations-1b130a99726b).

Answer (score 10):

A diferenças das duas é que a `useCallback` não é **executada** no render enquanto a `useMemo`é.

Isso cria a possibilidade de "guardar" a função para ser utilizada apenas por callbacks por exemplo, como o click de um botão ou dentro de um `useEffect`.

No trecho abaixo a `useMemo` vai ser executada no primeiro render, enquanto a `useCallback` só vai ser executada se você a executar, como no useEffect que está comentado ou no click do `button`

```js
const Component = () => {
  const testCallback = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('useCallback')
  }, [])

  const testMemo = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log('useMemo')
  }, [])

  // testCallback só é executada manualmente
  // useEffect(() => {
  //  testCallback()
  // }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => testCallback()}>Executar testCallback</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Detalhe importante: O `useMemo` não deve ser utilizado com o objetivo de "executar a função durante o render" ou qualquer coisa do gênero. Descrevo o uso correto na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/515273/100416). O `useMemo` está mais relacionado ao retorno das função do que à função em si.

Answer (score 3):

Uma boa forma de entender a diferença entre `useMemo` e `useCallback` é ver que é possível reproduzir o `useCallback` utilizando um `useMemo`.

Exemplo:

```js
const useCallback = useCallback(() => console.log('teste'), []);
const useCallbackUtilizandoUseMemo = useMemo(() => () => console.log('teste'), [])
```

`useMemo` executa a função inicialmente e somente executa novamente caso as dependências informadas sejam alteradas, enquanto que o useCallback não executa a função, mas sim retorna uma nova referencia dela quando as dependências mudam.