# O que faz o meu componente ser renderizado novamente no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Muito comumente vejo falarem que um componente do React será re-renderizado por causa de uma `prop`, estado, valor de [contexto](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) alterado, etc.

- Quais são os fatores que de fato influem na re-renderização de um componente?
- Nos componentes funcionais, há alguma relação com `useEffect`, `useMemo` ou `useCallback`?

Note que não estou querendo saber especificamente da *primeira* renderização, mas sim dos fatores que fazem uma segunda (ou terceira, quarta, etc) renderização ocorrer.

Não sei se, nesse assunto, há distinção entre os "componentes funcionais" e os (antigos) "componentes de classe". Se houver, gostaria que fosse enfatizado nos componentes funcionais, mas uma breve menção sobre isso em relação aos componentes de classe também seria bom.

Comment: é muito ampla, misturando hooks com component class que são diferentes o jeito de fazer, mas, o comportamento é o mesmo.

Comment: @novic, no final da pergunta eu preferi por colocar o enfoque nos próprios componentes funcionais (que dão a relação com os hooks), então não acho que de fato ocorre essa “mistura”...

Comment: A diferença é de como fazer, os estilos, isso mesmo estilos de programação, mas, o resultado final é o mesmo, eu entendi que você talvez queira apontar diferenças (`há distinção`) mas, de fato reforçando o código gerado é o mesmo. Talvez a nova versão tão aguardada seja diferente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resumo

A resposta ficou meio longa. Em resumo, o React possui um algoritmo que compara duas árvores de elementos no DOM para saber se deve atualizá-los ou não. Esse algoritmo atualizará a árvore DOM quando:

- O nó raiz da árvore é de tipo diferente (e.g. `<div> <a>Oi</a> </div>` e `<button> <a>Oi</a> </button>`);
- Algum atributo foi modificado (e.g. `<div className="a" />` e `<div className="b' />`);
- Alguma propriedade do componente foi modificada (e.g. `<Timer time={10} />` e `<Timer time={15} />`);
- Algum estado do componente foi modificado;
- A comparação de nós filhos encontra diferenças. Essa comparação é uma recursão nas duas árvores ao mesmo tempo, comparando nó a nó.

E, a relação com os *hooks* mencionados é simplesmente que eles são executados em toda renderização, mas fazem uso de um array de dependências para definir se o *callback* passado para estes hooks deve ser executado novamente ou não.

---

## Como funciona a re-renderização?

<sup>Este tópico e toda explicação do algoritmo de *diff* é com base na documentação [*Reconciliation*](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#motivation).</sup>

Sempre que o `render()` é executado em um componente classe, ou quando um componente funcional é executado, uma árvore de elementos é retornada. Quando o estado ou as propriedades são atualizadas, uma nova árvore é retornada. Então, o React precisa diferenciar as duas árvores para saber se precisa renderizar algo.

A re-renderização não desmonta e remonta os componentes. Ela apenas atualiza as diferenças encontradas de acordo com as regras definidas pelo algoritmo de *diff*, explicado abaixo.

### Algoritmo de *diff*

Para identificar as diferenças de uma forma computacionalmente barata, o React criou o seu próprio algoritmo de *diff*, implementando um algoritmo heurístico O(n) com base em duas premissas:

1. Dois elementos de tipos diferentes produzirão árvores diferentes;
2. O desenvolvedor pode sugerir quais elementos filho podem ser estáveis em diferentes renderizações com uma propriedade `key`.

O comportamento do *diff* varia de acordo com o tipo dos elementos raízes a serem comparados.

#### Elementos de tipos diferentes

Quando o nó raiz de uma árvore é modificado, o React desmontará toda a árvore e montará uma nova do zero. Por exemplo:

```html
<div>
  <Counter />
</div>

<span>
  <Counter />
</span>
```

O código acima fará com que o `Counter` seja remontado.

#### Elementos DOM do mesmo tipo

Ao atualizar elementos DOM do mesmo tipo, o React observa os atributos, atualizando apenas os atributos modificados. Por exemplo:

```html
<div className="before" title="stuff" />

<div className="after" title="stuff" />
```

Nesse caso, o React modificará apenas o `className` do nó. No caso do atributo `style`, o React consegue identificar qual propriedade foi modificada.

#### Componentes do mesmo tipo

Quando um componente atualiza, a instância é a mesma, então o estado é mantido entre as renderizações. O React atualiza as propriedades da instância do componente para corresponder ao novo elemento.

Após essa atualização das propriedades, o algoritmo de *diff* é executado, comparando o resultado anterior ao atual.

**Nota:** Como a documentação do *Reconciliation* mal cita o State, quero citar outra documentação aqui, a [*State and Lifecycle*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect). Esta diz que, graças à chamada do `setState`, o React sabe que houve uma mudança de estado, e então executa o `render()` para verificar o que deve ser modificado na tela. É por isso que você não pode modificar o estado diretamente, sem a chamada da função `setState()`.

Apesar do exemplo dado ser para componentes classe, essa informação pode ser levada para os componentes funcionais.

#### Recursão nos filhos

Por padrão, quando há recursão sobre os filhos de um nó DOM, o React apenas itera em ambas as listas de filhos ao mesmo tempo e gera uma mutação sempre que houver uma diferença. Por exemplo:

```html
<ul>
  <li>primeiro</li>
  <li>segundo</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>primeiro</li>
  <li>segundo</li>
  <li>terceiro</li>
</ul>
```

O React entenderá que o `<li>primeiro</li>` e `<li>segundo</li>` são iguais, e adicionará o nó `<li>terceiro</li>`. Por causa disso, inserir um elemento no começo ou no meio da lista fará com que mais de um elemento seja re-renderizado desnecessariamente.

#### Chaves (`key`)

Para resolver o problema citado acima, o React aceita o atributo `key` em qualquer elemento. Quando os filhos possuem uma `key` definida, ela é utilizada para verificar se representam o mesmo nó ou não, e então realizar a re-renderização quando necessário.

É por isso que utilizar o `index` como `key` nem sempre é uma opção válida. Acabaria na mesma situação de não utilizar `key` nenhuma.

Para mais informações sobre a propriedade `key`, leia [Para que serve e como definir a prop "key" no React?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514407/100416)

### Fatores de atenção

De acordo com o algoritmo explicado acima, surgem dois pontos de atenção:

1. O algoritmo não tentará combinar sub-árvores de diferentes tipos de componentes. Se você alternar entre dois tipos de componentes com saída muito semelhante, convém torná-los do mesmo tipo. Na prática, isso não é considerado um problema.
2. As chaves (`key`) devem ser estáveis, previsíveis e únicas. Chaves instáveis (como aquelas produzidas por `Math.random()` ou `Date.now()`) farão com que muitas instâncias de componentes e nós DOM sejam desnecessariamente recriados, o que pode causar degradação de desempenho e perda de estado em componentes filhos.

---

## Os hooks citados

### `useEffect` (ou `componentDidUpdate`)

Conforme a [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) diz, por padrão, os efeitos são executados após cada renderização concluída, mas você pode optar por executá-los apenas quando certos valores forem alterados (com base no array de dependência). Existe uma pergunta que aborda esse assunto: [O que é e por que devo fornecer um “array de dependências” para os hooks do React?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514236/100416)

### `useMemo`

O [`useMemo`](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) é executado durante a renderização e retorna um **valor** memoizado. Também recebe um array de dependências, fazendo com que o valor seja recalculado apenas quando uma dessas dependências for modificada. É útil para cálculos "caros".

### `useCallback`

Similar ao `useMemo`, o [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) retorna um **callback** memoizado (e não um valor). É útil para momentos que dependem da comparação por referência para evitar uma re-renderização.

Eu escrevi uma resposta mais aprofundada sobre o `useMemo` e `useCallback` em [Qual é a diferença entre os hooks useMemo e useCallback do React?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/515273/100416)

### O que eles têm em comum?

Todos esses *hooks* são executados a cada renderização. A questão é que eles aceitam um array de dependências para definir se a função de callback passada para eles deve ser de fato executada ou não.

Por exemplo, um array vazio como em `useCallback(() => {}, [])` significa que será executado apenas uma vez, já que nenhum valor será atualizado nas próximas renderizações (não existe nenhum valor no array).

Já no caso `useMemo(() => fatorial(count), [count])`, significa que sempre que houver uma renderização e `count` ter seu valor modificado, o `() => fatorial(count)` será executado.

Então, o array de dependências não causa uma re-renderização, mas ele é utilizado após a re-renderização para saber se o callback será executado ou não.

Answer (score 0):

Estou aprendendo e praticando React e suas dúvidas fritaram muitos dos meus neurônios hoje, sinceramente obrigado, depois de uma boa pesquisa encontrei um conteúdo muito bom que pode te ajudar eu creio(me ajudou) [guide to react rendering behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/).

- useMemo e useCallback são acionados na 'render phase' e são basicamente para otimização, mas não devem conter partes vitais.
- useEffect é acionado na 'commit phase' o que acontece depois da 'render phase' porque geralmente é reservado para conter código que pode causar inconsistência na UI.

[diagrama - render phase & commit phase](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

Answer (score 0):

Resposta curta:

Alterações de Constantes

Resposta longa:

useState retorna um array com sua primeira posição sendo a constante e a segunda posição sendo uma função para setar novos valores a essa constante.

```
const [user , setUser] = useState(null);
```

Ao longo do código ao usarmos o setUser vai fazer com que essa constante seja alterada, mas para que isso ocorra é preciso renderizar novamente o componente para que de fato a constante possa receber esse novo valor.

O useEffect só é disparado DEPOIS que o componente foi montado em tela, ou seja tudo que tem dentro dele é ignorado na primeira faze do render.

se voce tem:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{
  setUser({name:'stackOverflow'});
},[]);

return (
  {!user && <h1>Ainda sem usuario</h1>}
  {user && <h1>{user.name}</h1>}
)
```

O primeiro render o usuario é null.
Depois de renderizado é disparado o useEffect no qual vai fazer uma alteração de uma constante.
Como vimos acima a alteração de uma constante vai disparar o rerender.

Caso o useEffect nao tenha nenhuma alteração de estado por obviedade não vai disparar o segundo render. Mas em 99.9% dos caso (se não 100%) é utilizado o useEffect para executar algo que vá mudar a UI.